# Randomization in uvm

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

It would be great if you could help me in understanding how randomization works in UVM and what factors affect it apart from ntb_random_seed . I am observing a testcase which is using same ntb_random_seed is following different randomization only with the addition of display macros. Is it possible? I hope my question is clear. Let me know, if you need additional information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the 1800-2012 LRM section 18.14 on random stability. It lists the possible causes of instability. Older versions of the UVM had problems with the display macros, especially if you used things like the report catcher.